# Mainactor isolated or no?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, async-await, swift-concurrency

I have the following view model:

```
@MainActor
final class SomeViewModel {
    func loadFromService() async {
        do { 
            let dto = try await networkService.theServiceIneedHere()
            //process dto
            //state is a @Published property and observed by a SwiftUI view to update the UI.
            state = .success(viewData)
        } catch {
            state = .failure(someError)
        }
    }
}
```

My question here is, if `loadFromService` is called from my SwiftUI view task method and my SwiftUI view is not marked as a `@MainActor` then is `loadFromService()` running on the MainActor’s thread? ie it is not isolated?

Is the following a better approach to the above code?

```
final class SomeViewModel {
    func loadFromService() async {
        do {
            let dto = try await networkService.theServiceIneedHere()
            await handleServiceSuccess(with:dto)
        } catch {
            await MainActor.run {
                state = .failure(someError)
            }
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
private func handleServiceSuccess(with: DTO) {
    //process dto, update state here
    state = .success(viewData)
}
```

In the second approach I feel, `loadFromService` is detached from Mainthread and only when we need to update the UI, we switch back to the main thread.

Comment: If the purpose of the VM is to update the View just add MainActor to the VM. Personally i think MainActor.run should be the exception.

Comment: It depends on how `networkService` is defined. If it's in an `actor` then it runs on a seperate thread and returns to the main thread in the first example.

Comment: In SwiftUI the `View` struct hierarchy is the view model already, don't try to use classes or you'll run into major issues.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr

It is generally preferable to isolate the whole view model to the main actor, ensuring compile-time validation of our code and ensuring that all interaction with the view takes place in the correct context (namely, the main actor).

That having been said, you can do whatever you want, as long as you make sure that all access and updates happen on the main actor. But we generally want to enjoy compile-time verification of our code with the least syntactic noise. Your first example achieves that. And there is nothing there that will block the main thread. Your second example technically works, but adds unnecessary syntactic noise, sacrifices compile-time checks, and all for no observable benefit.

---

As you know, when updating a property for the view, the goal is to make sure that it can be accessed from (and publish updates to) the main thread. And, to ensure thread-safety, that means that we want *all* updates of that property to happen on the main thread, too.

In GCD, we achieve this by ensuring that everywhere we accessed or updated `state`, we would have to make sure we did that from the main thread (often sprinkling our code with `DispatchQueue.main.async {…}` everywhere we did so). We would have to use run-time diagnostics, like TSAN, to ensure we did not accidentally neglect to properly synchronize our access. Cautious programmers would also insert run-time checks to make sure we were on the main queue, too, with a `dispatchPrecondition(.onQueue(.main))`.

Swift concurrency reduces this burden by shifting away from this run-time “make sure I am on the correct queue” to an actor isolation pattern that provides compile-time validation for us, as well as ensuring that at run-time, things happen on the correct thread/actor.

So we will isolate the property, `state` to the main actor. Note, that the emphasis is on the isolation of the *property,* not the *method.* It is far more important to ensure that the property is isolated to the main actor than the actor isolation of the methods. This way, the compiler simply will not let you update the property from the incorrect isolation context. This lets us enjoy compile-time validation of our code (ensuring the correct run-time behavior), rather than relying on manual run-time burdens.

That having been said, we generally would isolate the methods that update this property to the main actor, too, resulting in less syntactic noise. Furthermore, given that the view model’s entire purpose is to interact with the view, we generally isolate the whole view model to the main actor, further reducing syntactic noise. But the key is that to enjoy compile-time validation of our code, make sure the *property* is isolated to the main actor.

---

For what it is worth, WWDC 2021’s [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/) walks through this whole process, shifting from GCD to `MainActor.run` and finally even retiring that in favor of main actor isolation.

Also, [SE-0316 Using global actors on a type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0316-global-actors.md#using-global-actors-on-a-type) says:

> It is common for entire types (and even class hierarchies) to predominantly require execution on the main thread, and for asynchronous work to be a special case. In such cases, the type itself can be annotated with a global actor, and all of the methods, properties, and subscripts will implicitly be isolated to that global actor.

A view model is a perfect use case for this pattern.

Finally, regarding `ObservableObject`, Apple explicitly suggests that these be isolated to the main actor in [Discover concurrency in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10019/?time=1290).

---

A few clarifications in your text. You say:

> My question here is, if `loadFromService` is called from my SwiftUI view task method and my SwiftUI view is not marked as a `@MainActor` then is `loadFromService()` running on the MainActor thread? ie it is not isolated?

Just to be clear, if the whole view model is isolated to the main actor (which is a fine/recommended practice), then `loadFromService` is also isolated to the main actor. Unlike GCD, it doesn’t matter where you called it from; the governing factor is that the whole type is isolated to the main actor and therefore its methods (except those explicitly designated as `nonisolated`) are also isolated to the main actor.

You also said:

> In the second approach I feel, `loadFromService` is detached from [the main thread] and only when we need to update the UI, we switch back to the main thread.

Sure, but this is not generally needed. This method is not doing anything that would block the main thread. The only thing relevant that it is doing is calling the network service method (but the presence of the `await` keyword means that this method is suspended while the network service does its work, meaning the main thread is free to ensure that the UI continues to be responsive).

Worse, this second approach may even be slower (though perhaps not observably so). This is because the non-isolated `async` function will switch from the view’s main thread to a generic executor (see [SE-0338](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md)), and then when you reach the `await`, it will likely switch to another asynchronous context.

The only thing you need to be careful of is to ensure that the view model methods do nothing that is slow and *synchronous.* But if you have an `await`, then that is asynchronous, and you are generally in good shape.

Comment: Thank you Rob for that elaborate explanation. I understand now, thank you clearing my doubts. Suppose there is a scenario where my view model inherits from another class, say some analytics class. In this case I get a warning if only my view model is marked as MainActor and my analytics class is not. How do you suggest handling such situations?

Comment: Could you kindly explain why having a view model as a subclass of a analytics class is a bad idea? Is it because its would blur the separation of concerns? Would it then be a better idea if the view model would implement a protocol responsible for analytics and the concrete implementation of sending events be handled elsewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257247/discussion-between-rob-and-rakshith-nandish).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer for your question:

> No. Your `networkService.theServiceIneedHere()` method is not forced to run on the main thread unless you mark it as `@MainActor` explicitly.

So in your first example, the function in network service is executed on any thread and state is updated on main. `@MainActor` of your viewModel affects the scope of viewModel not nested async functions called by this class.

Regarding your View:

> SwiftUI View body getter is already marked as MainActor in its protocol. So every code block in your body is executed on main thread even if you use `Task {}` since `Task` inherits the calling actor.

---

First approach would be my preferred way. Because then you don't need to switch to the main thread before updating any UI parameter (most likely @Published properties).

I'm not familiar with the new `@Observable` yet but this is at least my suggestion for `@ObservableObject` since you store your properties as `@Published` and update them in view model.

Comment: Why do you think only the 1st approach is correct? The 2nd approach is also correct, since the `@Published` property is updated from a `@MainActor` method. You don't need to make the whole view model `@MainActor` necessarily, you only need to ensure that properties which update the `View` are updated from the main actor.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Because a ViewModel is most likely `ObservableObject` or `@Observable` which has bunch of @Published properties. They all should be updated on main thread. Otherwise you have to always switch to main thread and update UI properties. Having MainActor on `handleServiceSuccess` will not force it to run on main thread. You have to always switch to main before calling it or call it from other context marked as MainActor.

Comment: @loremipsum you can simply check implementation of View protocol. As I mentioned, body is MainActor `@ViewBuilder @MainActor var body: Self.Body { get }`

Comment: I missed the body part, the view isn't but the body is

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz updating a property from an `@MainActor` method ensures that the property is updated from the main thread. "Having MainActor on handleServiceSuccess will not force it to run on main thread." is simply not correct. I'd suggest you give it a try yourself and you'll see.

Comment: Yes you are right @DávidPásztor, but looks like this is fixed in Swift 5.6, isn't it? Because with Swift 5.5, adding main actor to a method doesn't force you to call it via await. As also mentioned [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/mainactor-doesnt-work-or-misunderstood/56222). But when I try with Swift 5.9 now, I see it works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

In SwiftUI you shouldn't have any view models at all because that is what the `View` struct is designed for. Don't put your funcs in classes, put them somewhere else, like a struct. In general in Swift avoid classes and aim to use structs first, see the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing-between-structures-and-classes

If your async `func` is in the `View` struct it runs on main thread, if it's in the `View` struct but is marked `nonisolated` it runs on background thread, but the best place is in another struct because then will run on background thread by default.

An `EnvironmentKey` struct is a good place for a bunch of service async funcs that return things because then you can mock them for Previews, e.g.

```
struct ContentView {

    @Environment(\.service) var service
    @State var results: [Result] = []

    var body: some View {
       ...
       .task {
            results = await service.fetchResults()
       }
    }
}

struct Service {

    // runs on background thread
    func fetchResults() async -> [Results] {
        return ...
    }
}
```